# Why should we make sure the calculated MD5 is of length 32?

Tags: hashing

I see when people write code on calculating MD5, (even in the documentation), they write like this:

```
IntegerString[Hash[something, "MD5"], 16, 32]
```

But I think that `Hash[something, "MD5"]` already returns the 128-bit MD5, and I observed that `IntegerString[Hash[something, "MD5"], 16]` would always give the same result as the code above. So why is that 32 present?

Comment: Leading zeros...

Comment: @ciao I know what that option mean, but I don't see a case when the hash itself does not exceed 32chars or longer than that.

Comment: @Felix: see below...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
IntegerString[Hash["363", "MD5"], 16] // StringLength

(* 30 *)

IntegerString[Hash["a", "MD5"], 16] // StringLength

(* 31 *)
```

Here's a whopper found Googlin':

```
IntegerString[Hash["jk8ssl", "MD5"], 16,32]
IntegerString[Hash["jk8ssl", "MD5"], 16] // StringLength

(* 0000000018e6137ac2caab16074784a6 *)
(* 24 *)
```

Comment: So `Hash` automatically removes the 0 in the front. I see.

Comment: @Felix: not exactly, `Hash` returns a number (`Integer`), for which something like leading zeros does not really exist. It is `IntegerString` which would not pad the (hex) string representation of that number with zeros unless you tell it...

Answer (score 5):

As of version 11.3.0, it is no longer necessary to use `IntegerString`.

Also, the correct padding will be added automatically by `Hash`, for example

```
Hash["jk8ssl", "MD5", "HexString"]

(* "0000000018e6137ac2caab16074784a6" *)
```